# Deducing the const (return) type with decltype and auto

Tags: c++

Why does `decltype` deduce `const` from a variable but not from a function?

```
const int f()
{
    const int i = 1;
    return i;
}
decltype(auto) i_fromFunc = f(); // i_fromFunc is of type 'int'

const int i = 1;
decltype(auto) i_fromVar = i; // i_fromVar is of type 'const int'
```

---

Example with more deduction variants ([see at compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/g/EzEaSz)).

```
const int func()
{
    const int i = 1;
    return i;
}

decltype(auto) funcDecltype()
{
    const int i = 1;
    return i;        
}

auto funcAuto()
{
    const int i = 1;
    return i;
}

void DeduceFromFunc()
{
    decltype(auto) i = func(); // i is of type 'int', similar to auto i = func()
    i = 2;
    decltype(auto) iDT = funcDecltype(); // iDT is of type 'int', similar to auto iDT = funcDecltype()
    iDT = 2;
    decltype(auto) iA = funcAuto(); // iA is of type 'int', similar to auto iA = funcAuto().
    iA = 2;

    // For the sake of completeness:

    const auto ci = func(); // const int
    //ci = 2; // Not mutable.

    //auto& iRef = func(); // non const lvalue of 'int&' can't bind to rvalue of 'int'
    const auto& ciRef = func(); // const int &
    //ciRef = 2; // Not mutable.

    auto&& iRV = func(); // int &&
    iRV = 2;
    const auto&& ciRV = func(); // const int &&
    //ciRV = 2; // Not mutable.
}

const int gi = 1;

void DeduceFromVar()
{
    auto i_fromVar = gi; // i_fromVar is of type 'int'.
    i_fromVar = 2;
    decltype(auto) iDT_fromVar = gi; // iDT_fromVar is of type 'const int'
    //iDT = 2; // Not mutable.

    // For the sake of completeness:
    auto& iRef = gi; // reference to const int
    //iRef = 2; // Not mutable.
    auto&& iRVRef = gi; // rvalue ref to const int
    //iRVRef = 2; // Not mutable.
}

int main()
{
    DeduceFromFunc();
    DeduceFromVar();
}
```

Why the constness of `iDT_fromVar` differs from `i_fromVar`? (`decltype(auto)` vs `auto` for vars)

Why the constness of `iDT_fromVar` differs from `iDT`? (question from above)

Why `i_fromVar` and `i`/`iDT`/`iA` have the same constness when `iDT_fromVar` and `iDT` have not?

Comment: IIRC, the `const` in your function declaration is discarded by the compiler. `const int foo();` is the same as `int foo()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no `const` prvalues of non-class type. The function `const int f()` is basically equivalent to `int f()`.

The relevant clause in C++17 is [expr]/6:

> If a prvalue initially has the type “cv `T` ”, where `T` is a cv-unqualified non-class, non-array type, the type of the expression is adjusted to `T` prior to any further analysis.

You would see different behaviour if trying similar code with a class type instead of `int` as the return type.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning prvalue. So *prior to any further analysis* seems to imply before `decltype` and `auto` are evaluated. At cppreference for Value categories [it is stated](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) *a function call or cast expression may result in a prvalue of non-class cv-qualified type, but the cv-qualifier is immediately stripped out* which results in the same.